# Get deltas from an array using foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I am trying to show some values using json api. It returns a date and some density value in numbers. Successfully, I have printed all return values from url. Now, I want to find the difference between one density value to previous day density value.

I know how to calculate the difference in normal static numbers. But, I am not sure how do I achieve this inside a `foreach` loop.

**PHP Code:**

```
$json_url = "https://www.example.com/api";

$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$obj  = json_decode($json,true);
$data = $obj["data"];

foreach(array_slice($data, 0, 10) as $k) {

    echo $k["date"]." - ".$k["density"]."<br/><br/>";

}
```

**Current Output:**

```
14-02-2020 - 110

13-02-2020 - 114

12-02-2020 - 112

11-02-2020 - 110

10-02-2020 - 105

07-02-2020 - 125

06-02-2020 - 122

05-02-2020 - 118

04-02-2020 - 119

03-02-2020 - 119
```

**Expected Output:**

```
14-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is -4 from Previous Date

13-02-2020 - 114 - Diff is +2 from Previous Date

12-02-2020 - 112 - Diff is +2 from Previous Date

11-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is +5 from Previous Date

10-02-2020 - 105 - Diff is -20 from Previous Date

07-02-2020 - 125 - Diff is +3 from Previous Date

06-02-2020 - 122 - Diff is +4 from Previous Date

05-02-2020 - 118 - Diff is -1 from Previous Date

04-02-2020 - 119 - No Difference - Same

03-02-2020 - 119 - No Difference - Same
```

Comment: please post JSON string too

Comment: That final row being +1 doesn't make logical sense to me.  Please explain.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, you are correct. That's my mistake. I will show like this `03-02-2020 - 119`

Comment: With no diff text?  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired effect you will need to iterate the array two elements at a time. This can't easily be done with `foreach` outright. So instead I will implement a generator that returns pairs of values from the array at a time.

```
function getPairs(Array $array) {
    reset($array);
    do {
        $a1  = current($array);
        $key = key($array);
        $a2  = next($array);
        yield [$a1, $a2];
    } while($key = key($array) !== null);
}
```

You can then use this generator implementation to traverse the array, attaining the desired effect.

```
$array = [
    ["date" => "14-02-2020", "density" => 110],
    ["date" => "13-02-2020", "density" => 114],
    ["date" => "12-02-2020", "density" => 112],
    ["date" => "11-02-2020", "density" => 110],
    ["date" => "10-02-2020", "density" => 105],
    ["date" => "07-02-2020", "density" => 125],
    ["date" => "12-02-2020", "density" => 112],
    ["date" => "06-02-2020", "density" => 122],
    ["date" => "05-02-2020", "density" => 118],
    ["date" => "04-02-2020", "density" => 119],
    ["date" => "03-02-2020", "density" => 119],
];

foreach(getPairs($array) as [$a, $b]) {
    // We must check if $b is empty to account for end of the array
    if ($b) {
        $diff = $a["density"] - $b["density"];
    } else { // Otherwise there are no more elements to diff against
        $diff = 0;
    }
    if ($diff > 0) {
        $diff = "+$diff";
    }
    echo "{$a['date']} - {$a['density']} - Diff is $diff from Previous Date<br><br>";
}
```

This should give you the desired output.

```
14-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is -4 from Previous Date

13-02-2020 - 114 - Diff is +2 from Previous Date

12-02-2020 - 112 - Diff is +2 from Previous Date

11-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is +5 from Previous Date

10-02-2020 - 105 - Diff is -20 from Previous Date

07-02-2020 - 125 - Diff is +13 from Previous Date

12-02-2020 - 112 - Diff is -10 from Previous Date

06-02-2020 - 122 - Diff is +4 from Previous Date

05-02-2020 - 118 - Diff is -1 from Previous Date

04-02-2020 - 119 - Diff is 0 from Previous Date

03-02-2020 - 119 - Diff is 0 from Previous Date
```

> ### N.B.
>
> Technically speaking you aren't actually getting the difference between the current date and the previous date, here. Rather, you are getting the difference between the current date and the **next** date. If you were getting the deltas between previous dates you wouldn't need the information from the next date at all. Instead you'd just use a temporary variable to store the last `density` value and diff against that with each iteration. However, I've tailored my answer to suit your expected result.

Otherwise the expected output would actually be:

```
14-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is +110 from Previous Date

13-02-2020 - 114 - Diff is +4 from Previous Date

12-02-2020 - 112 - Diff is -2 from Previous Date

11-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is -2 from Previous Date

10-02-2020 - 105 - Diff is -5 from Previous Date

07-02-2020 - 125 - Diff is +20 from Previous Date

12-02-2020 - 112 - Diff is -13 from Previous Date

06-02-2020 - 122 - Diff is +10 from Previous Date

05-02-2020 - 118 - Diff is -4 from Previous Date

04-02-2020 - 119 - Diff is +1 from Previous Date

03-02-2020 - 119 - Diff is 0 from Previous Date
```

And to achieve that you don't need the generator implementation I used at all. You can simply do this with a regular `foreach` loop like so:

```
$lastDiff = 0; // Initialize the diff to 0

foreach($array as $a) {
    $date = $a['date'];
    $density = $a['density'];
    $diff = $a["density"] - $lastDiff; // diff against the last known value
    if ($diff > 0) {
        $diff = "+$diff";
    }
    echo "$date - $density - Diff is $diff from Previous Date<br><br>";
    $lastDiff = $a["density"]; // store the last known density here for the next iteration
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works except last case. It didn't work in last case if I use `array_slice($commits, 0, 10)`..

Comment: Well, you have to account for the fact that in the last case there will be nothing to diff against. Say the array is `[1,2,2]`. The first pair is `[1,2]` the second pair is `[2,2]`and the last pair is actually `[2]` because there is nothing left in the array. So in that case you must check if `$b` actually exists.

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for this edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative, shorter version.  This just works on a straight `for()` loop, working with the current and next items.  The loop stops at the second from last one as the last one will always be the same as the *next one*...

```
$end = count($array)-1;
for ( $i = 0; $i < $end; $i++ ) {
    if ( $array[$i]["density"] == $array[$i+1]["density"] )    {
        echo "No Difference - Same".PHP_EOL;
    }
    else    {
        echo "Diff is ".($array[$i]["density"]-$array[$i+1]["density"])." from Previous Date".PHP_EOL;
    }

}
echo "No Difference - Same".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: See comment from OP about not bothering to append text on final iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in a single loop and use the `printf()` function to format the signed values.

I'm writing `\n\n` in place of your `<br><br>` so that my demo renders properly.

I find this snippet easy to read and manage.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/g4UJT))

```
$prev = null;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($prev !== null) {
        $diff = $prev - $row['density'];
        if (!$diff) {
            echo " - No Difference - Same\n\n";
        } else {
            printf(" - Diff is %+d from Next Date\n\n", $diff);
        }
    }
    echo "{$row['date']} - {$row['density']}";
    $prev = $row['density'];
}
```

Output:

```
14-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is -4 from Next Date

13-02-2020 - 114 - Diff is +2 from Next Date

12-02-2020 - 112 - Diff is +2 from Next Date

11-02-2020 - 110 - Diff is +5 from Next Date

10-02-2020 - 105 - Diff is -20 from Next Date

07-02-2020 - 125 - Diff is +3 from Next Date

06-02-2020 - 122 - Diff is +4 from Next Date

05-02-2020 - 118 - Diff is -1 from Next Date

04-02-2020 - 119 - No Difference - Same

03-02-2020 - 119
```